# Weird update error

Tags: updates, appcenter

Just saw this this afternoon. Is there a problem with an update that's coming down?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any alternative repositories (e.g. ppa for a particular software) active?

If you do, try disabling them and see if the error persists. Sometimes external ppa's don't come with authentication information.

If the error persists without external repositories, see if an

```
sudo apt update
```

gets rid of the error message and let us know anything you have found out.

Comment: I ran the updates again this morning and that error didn't come up. Maybe it was just a temporary glitch or something. Everything's fine now